# How to close a WebView with double-click?

Tags: android, webview, double-click

I writed a activity just with a WebView that runs on an Android.

The problem is

I want to close the activity through double-click.

I use "GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener" faction "onDoubleTap(android.view.MotionEvent e)"

but it donnot work .

How I can do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little stuff I did for you (in order to improve myself and help you btw :) )
Tried it and it worked pretty well ;)
:

```
package com.spinner.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    GestureDetector gs = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wvView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewid);

        wvView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gs == null) {
                    gs = new GestureDetector(
                            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                                    MyActivity.this.finish();
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                }
                gs.onTouchEvent(event);

                return false;
            }
        });
        wvView.loadUrl("http://www.google.fr");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I loadurl "file:///android_asset/first.html" the webview can no roll, I donnot know why.

Comment: "WebView can no roll", I'm not sure to understand what you mean ?!
Anyway, please mark my answer if it helped you! Thanks

Comment: But if I loadurl "file:///android_asset/first.html", the webview  did not respond when I click the web page.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with you first.html, if it has some javascript in it or W/E...

Comment: I found there was something wrong with the "first.html", it work now! Thank you!