# Make a Double Click work in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, overriding, double-click, simulate

I have a Website that has some double click functionality and so with android when you double click in the browser it will just zoom.  So I am building a WebView so I can over ride the double click and make it react like it should.

```
public class myWebView extends Activity{

GestureDetector gs = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    engine.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
           }
    });
    engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

    engine.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gs == null) {
                gs = new GestureDetector(
                        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                            //overrides the double click
                            @Override
                            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                                // SOME CODE THAT SIMULATES A DOUBLE CLICK
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
            }
            gs.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    engine.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

So the function onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) will do whatever is in between in the event of a double click.  [The above code is mostly thanks too Cehm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294572/1366422).

So at this point I need to trick it to executing a a double click.  Can I just simulate a Couple of click in there?

Comment: Its a really bad idea to ignore the UI conventions for a platform.  The double tap gesture to zoom in is well known and used by users, if you start using it to do different things you're only going to make users angry.

Comment: Well I am doing it only for a specific web site that a large companies uses for its employees and needs the double click functionality.  I am not trying to replace the web browser for the android.  I am simply trying to make a small app for a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try it once :

```
private GestureDetector gs = null;

private OnTouchListener onTouch = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (gs == null) {
            gs = new GestureDetector(
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {

                            //Double Tap
                            snapWebView.zoomIn();//Zoom in
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

                            //Single Tab
                            snapWebView.zoomOut();// Zoom out
                            return false;
                        };
                    });
        }

        gs.onTouchEvent(event);

        return false;
    }
};
```

Finally, set OnTouch event to WebView:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
```

See detail: [How to make Double Click in WebView?](http://thinkandroidsimple.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-snippets-double-click-webview.html)